# Reading from a textfile into an array into the C programming language

Tags: c, file, input

How do I read into an array a string with space in it, delimited with semicolons from a textfile in the C programming language?

```
***from textfile***
"My Record; My Second Record; My Third"
```

.
.
.

```
    fopen ...
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    fscanf_s(myFile, "%s", myRecords[i].title); /* this want read the records */
    }
    fclose...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious possibility would be to use the `scanset` conversion:

```
fscanf_s(myFile, "%[^;]", myRecords[i].title);
```

Comment: The format should be " %[^;];" to skip the leading space and to read the semicolon.  The third record in the textfile should have a semicolon terminator, consequently.

Comment: Ok great and I followed your comment Steve.

Comment: fscanf(file, "%30[^;];", myRecords[i].title)

Where 30 is the maximum number of characteres to be read, and 30 is just an example you can change it to whatever number you want.

I didn't test it, it may be unaccurate.. go here for more info...